# Android App .aab not connecting to Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, android-app-bundle

Android Studio (AS) Flamingo 2022.2.1

I have a Google Maps (GM) app (API 31) on the Play Store that works fine.
I coded an update in AS to API 33 by changing the version number only and new dependancies.
It builds fine.
I built this update to /RELEASE/*.apk using the same keystore and tested on a real device.
The .apk GM works fine.
I then built an *.aab to /RELEASE using the same keystore and published to the Play Store.
The GM with the new .aab from the Play Store no workie.

So the question is: Why does GM work in the release .apk, but not a release .aab?

I've double checked the SHA cert and namespace on the Cloud Console and everything's the same.

Thank you.